# como puedo hacer un método que me genere un auto numérico

Tags: java, sql

Lo que deseo obtener es que mediante un método java que no tiene parámetros y que me devuelva un entero; dentro del método debe leerse el último número utilizado en una tabla SQL que lo capture y lo convierta en int para poderlo sumar

```
public static int codigo() throws SQLException{        
    Connection cnConexion=Database.getConexion();

    int codEmp=0;
    PreparedStatement psCod=null;
    ResultSet rCod=null;

    try{
        String consultaNum = "SELECT MAX(CAST(codigo as int)) as numero from Persona";

        psCodE=cnConexion.prepareStatement(consultaNum);

        rCodE=psCodE.executeQuery();            
        rCodE.next();            
        codEmp=rCodE.getInt("numero");

        rCodE.close();
        psCodE.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        throw e;
    }
    finally{ 
        try{
            cnConexion.close();               
        }catch(Exception e){
            Logger.getLogger("Error al cerrar conexión codigo: " ,e);            
        }
    }

    return codEmp;
}
```

lo ejecute como esta descrito y si me muestra el último numero utilizado, pero en el código lo modifique para ver si me aparecía el siguiente  pero me muestra solo 0, este es el código modificado en el try:

```
try{
        String consultaNum = "SELECT MAX(CAST(codigo as int)) as numero from rol_0001";

        psCodE=cnConexion.prepareStatement(consultaNum);

        rCodE=psCodE.executeQuery();             
        codEmp=rCodE.getInt("numero");
        codEmp++;

        rCodE.close();
        psCodE.close();
    }
```

me pueden decir que me falta, gracias

Comment: te da algun error? si todo esta bien solo debes sumar uno al numero que te devuelve

Comment: si, al momento de utilizarla me da error entre los paréntesis y me dice que no se ha declarado la exception aunque si se la ha descrito; le puse la sugerencia del netbeans del import java.lang.Exception y me deja continuar pero no visualizo el nuevo número

Comment: Pone algo dentro del catch. A ver si esta ocurriendo un error.

Answer (score 0):

Una opcion seria crear una secuencia:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[SEQ_CODE] AS BIGINT START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1
```

y ejecutar lo siguiente para que te devuelva el valor:

```
SELECT @AUTO = NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_CODE AS VALOR
```